# CSS classes conflicting

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate a card flipping face up and then fading out. I do this by adding a class 'flipped' on click and a second 'vanish' after a timeout of 2 seconds. However, as soon as the 'vanish' class is added, the card flips back face down. I don't understand why, as the 'flipped' class is still applied.

Here is my mark up:

```
<div class="grid-space">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front-face">
        <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/lwcqviihu/image/upload/v1512898858/Animals/Sloth_svg.svg"/>
        <p>sloth</p>
      </div>
      <div class="back-face"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS (flipped and vanish classes marked)

```
    body {
      background: #333;
    }

    .grid-space {
      perspective: 1000;
      width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .grid-space:hover {
      transform: scale(1.02);
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    } 

    .card {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      display: flex;
      border-radius: 1vw;
      transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
      cursor: pointer; 
    }

    .card p {
      color: inherit;
    }

/*****These are the classes applied to do the animation***********/

    .flipped {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .vanish {
      opacity: 0;
    }

/*****END**********************************************************/

    .front-face, .back-face {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border-radius: 1vw;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .front-face {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      color: #EDCB7A;
      background: #487360;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
    }

    .back-face {
      /* background: #C7C6C4;
      border: 1px solid #EBD787; */
      background: #3A295C;
      border: 1px #EBD787 solid;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .front-face > p {
      font-size: 3vmin;
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .front-face > img {
      width: 90%;
      margin-top: 5%;
    }
```

And finally, the javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[0];
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className += " flipped";
    window.setTimeout(vanish, 2000);
  });

  function vanish() {
    card.className += " vanish";
  }
};
```

You can see the whole thing 'working' here: https://codepen.io/timsig/pen/MVavXv

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: what is your question exactly? is it, why the `flipped` class is still applied or is it, why the card is flipping back face down after `vanish` class is added?

Comment: Timbo wants the card to flip from back to front, revealing the image, then fade out with the image still face up. Currently it reverts to showing the back side of the card before fading away.

Comment: Create a working snippet here. No external sites necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be something odd hiding the revealed face when applying opacity to the parent.

I sinceriously don't know why that happens (if anyone has a clue, I'd really, really like to know), but an alternate approach would be to modify the faces instead of the card itself when you apply the .vanish class

```
.vanish > .back-face{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.vanish > .front-face{
  opacity:0
}

.front-face{
  transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

and of course, taking out the rule that applies opacity 0 to the .card

```
/*.vanish {
  opacity: 0;
}*/
```

Comment: That works like a charm - many thanks, and thanks Joseph Webber for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why it's happening. When `.card`'s opacity is being set to 0 because of `.vanish`, it's setting the opacity of its default state since the opacity style is being set on `.card` itself.
I fixed it by moving the opacity styles to `.front-face` since that's the side you want to fade out.

```
.card {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.vanish .front-face {
  opacity: 0;
}
.front-face {
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```